# Match an IMDb url in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match an IMDb url, but I keep getting the following error:

```
/(^http://imdb\.com/title/tt(\d)+/\.+season=(\d)+(.+)?$)
|(^http://imdb\.com/title/tt(\d)+/(.+)?$)
/.test('http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0429046/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1')
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

What is this error and what should the correct input be?

Another option I could do is the broader:

```
/imdb.com\/title\/tt(\d)+/(.+)?$/.test('http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0429046/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1')
```

However, for this one I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the `/`s within your regex, ie: `http:\/\/` ...etc.

Comment: I then get anUncaught Syntax Error: `/imdb.com\/title\/tt(\d)+/(.+)?$/.test('http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0429046/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1')

Comment: You still have an unescaped `/` after the `(\d)+`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working RegEx:

```
/(^http:\/\/www\.imdb\.com\/title\/tt(\d)+\/\.+season=(\d)+(.+)?$)|(^http:\/\/www\.imdb\.com\/title\/tt(\d)+\/(.+)?$)/
```

### [Demo](http://www.regexr.com/39sb7)

Answer (score 0):

@smithy is correct answer.

Here they are escaped.

First one  `/(^http:\/\/imdb\.com\/title\/tt(\d)+\/\.+season=(\d)+(.+)?$)|(^http:\/\/imdb\.com\/title\/tt(\d)+\/(.+)?$)/`

```
     (
          ^ http://imdb\.com/title/tt
          ( \d )+
          /
          \.+ season =
          ( \d )+
          ( .+ )?
          $ 
     )
  |  (
          ^ http://imdb\.com/title/tt
          ( \d )+
          /
          ( .+ )?
          $ 
     )
```

Second one  `/imdb\.com\/title\/tt(\d)+\/(.+)?$/`

```
 imdb \. com/title/tt
 ( \d )+
 /
 ( .+ )?
 $
```